# how to check SPI signals

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, avr

I am working with ATmega32-A micro controller. I am trying to read ADC (AD7798) values. I am setting ADC registers as shown below. Images also attached.

```
char spi(char data)
{
    //Start transmision
    SPDR = data;
    //Wait for transmision complete
    while(!(SPSR & 0x80));
    return SPDR;
} 

void setupAd(){
    ADC_CS=0; 
    SPCR = 0x5D;
    spi(0x10);   //set up communication register for configuration reg (16bit).
    spi(0x07);    // sending 07 as MSB     
    spi(0x10);    //sending 10 as LSB 
    ADC_CS=1; 
}
```

I am trying to read this configuration setup using this

```
void ReadAdConfReg(void)
{              
    SPCR = 0x5D;
    ADC_CS=0;
    spi(0x50);
    adcConfig = spi(0xFF)<<8;
    adcConfig |= spi(0xFF);   
    ADC_CS=1;
}
```

printing like this

```
ReadAdConfReg();
printf("configreg:%d",adcConfig);
```

But my problem setup of that configuration registor was not working. I have checked with oscilloscope any mistakes in clock polarity and chip select. I have attached images as shown below.[image: Clock and write (MOSI)(Din pin of ADC)]
[image: Clock and Read (MISO)(Dout pin of ADC)]
[image: Clock and chip select]

Please help me why i am not able to set configuration register. clock polarities and chip select every thing ok according to ATmega32-A data sheet and AD7798 datasheet. please help me what mistake i am doing. or If I want to check my configuration register setup on oscilloscope What i have to do.

Comment: What is the yellow trace?  MOSI?  What about MISO?  Do you have a 4 channel scope so you can see all the signals?  You can go bit by bit and see exactly what you sent and exactly what you receive.  One of those won't be what you expect.

Comment: Also, don't try and start with something like writing a config register. If SPI isn't working yet, start by just doing the simplest command like reading the chip ID.  That way you know exactly what to expect.

Comment: @TJD yes, blue signal is colck, Yellow is MISO, MOSI, CS in diffrent images. I am reciving what i am sending. I have tried to read Id register it giving value"48". But in the data sheet Id register contains"0xX8". So i am confusing where is the fault either in SPI or Register setup or readsetup.

Comment: @verenda: when you say that reading the ID register gives a value "48" do you mean 48 decimal or 0x48?  The latter seems to be a correct response.

Comment: @MichaelBurr it gives decimal "48". So it is not equivalent to 0xX8. So i am thinking where is the fault. Either in reading or SPI function but SPI function working good I think. I am transmitting some values.

Comment: Can you replace the images with ones that show the ID register being read?  Also, you mention that the 1st image is MISO, but it looks to me like it's MOSI.

Comment: Is there any reason why the MOSI/MISO data isn't active for exactly the same amount of time as the 8 clock bits? Your data signals seem to have a life beyond the clock. That seems strange to me, SPI is supposed to behave as a shift register. Is this some sort of bit-banging code? Also, has this MCU and/or the slave got an option to level-trig, rather than edge-trig? If so, you could be getting clock skew with half a bit off, and that could possibly explain why the data isn't following the clock.

Comment: Actually it seems like the MCU holds the latest state of the pin? That's probably not a good idea, especially not if there are more slaves than one on the bus. Would a pull-up resistor solve anything or does the MCU actively drive the pin to the latest state?

Comment: Now I have solved the problem.

Comment: @verendra Care to share the solution with us? It is perfectly fine to post the answer to your own question, if it will help future readers.

Comment: why did you remove the images?

Comment: @BenVoigt, Agreed, I upvoted this question because the user added helpful information (the pictures) - why were they removed?

Comment: @Ben Voigt I thought images are not useful for this question because mistake is with read functions.

Comment: @verendra: There is not a 1:1 correlation between a question and your problem.  This question was about whether the SPI timing was correct.  The images were the most important part of that question.  The answer is that "the timing is correct".  You can mention what fixed your problem, but that's only tangentially related to your question about the waveforms.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Ok i will add it now.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the functions to read  8 bit and 16 bit registers then it worked.

```
unsigned int Bit_16(unsigned char cmd, unsigned int value) 
{
    unsigned int data; 
    SPCR = 0x5D;        // mode #3 F_CPU/16 
    ADC_CS = 0;                 // enable 
    spi(cmd);                   //Place instruction in communication register 
    data = spi(value >> 8);     // read hi-byte 
    data = (data << 8) | spi(value);    // and lo-byte. 
    ADC_CS = 1;                 // disable 
    return data; 
}
```

for write

```
AD7798_16(0x08, 0x000A);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the ADC datasheet more closely.

For each communication with the ADC you need to send a value for the communication register.  Per the datasheet, CR7 must be low or no other bits are clocked into the communication register.

So for the first byte you send it must have the MSB cleared.

Bit 6 is whether you want a read or a write.
Bits 5-3 are what register you want to operate on.
Bit 2 is whether you want to continuously read
Bits 1-0 should be 0's.

Please look over the datasheet's "Digital Interface" section, as well as the "On-Chip Registers" section.

Comment: Yes I have done that. I have that task more than 100 times. I have set all configuration right. You can see in the above code what I have set for communication register.